# Weird characters in MPI_File_write

Tags: c++, io, mpi, c++14

I copied the following example from  [Using MPI-2: Advanced Features of the Message-Passing Interface](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/usingmpi2/) but the output file is just weired characters. I tried to change the data types from int to char but the output is still the same. I tried to open the open the outputfile with different programs like Notepadqq and gedit. I tried also to open the file with different file formats and adding null pointer to the end of the file through process zero but the results are still weired characters.

```
/* example of parallel MPI write into a single file */
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#define BUFSIZE 100


int main( int argc, char **argv )

{
    int i, MyRank, NumProcs, buf[BUFSIZE];
    MPI_File TheFile;
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &MyRank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&NumProcs);
    for (i=0; i<BUFSIZE; i++)
        buf[i]=MyRank*BUFSIZE+i;
    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "testfile",MPI_MODE_CREATE|MPI_MODE_WRONLY,MPI_INFO_NULL, &TheFile);
    MPI_File_set_view(TheFile,MyRank*BUFSIZE*sizeof(int),MPI_INT,MPI_INT,"native",MPI_INFO_NULL);
    MPI_File_write(TheFile,buf,BUFSIZE,MPI_INT,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
// THis is my trial
    if(MyRank == 0){
        char nullChar = '\0';
        MPI_File_write(TheFile, & nullChar , 1 , MPI_CHAR ,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE );
    }

    MPI_File_close(&TheFile);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The program does not ensure that process zero will run last .. My first mistake. However even if I make all process write  the null pointer using the same way , the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

Because you are opening a binary file and you expect to see meaningful characters (not gonna happen). Look [here](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/asciiBin.html) for the difference between binary and text files. You can always read the data with `MPI_File_read()`.